# MySQL trigger find a column after event

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have a trigger which updates a value in another before an insert/update/delete occurs.

What I want to do is find the value of a specific column in the row that was just added, and use that value in my insert or update.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create additional table and log all changes. Inside triggers you can access old, new values by using `NEW`, `OLD` prefixes. Put them all (if you need all values which had been changed) into the log table.

Logging can be different. You can create table with the same structure with new columns {log_id, log_dtm}. Or if you need to log only certain fields you can create log table: {log_id, table, field, value, log_dtm} (or something like this).

Off course, to do it you should change your triggers to add new functionality.